# Yesod: parseRoutes depending on approot

Tags: haskell, yesod

My Yesod-Application should get it's approot via an Envoirement-Variable. [This](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/environment-variables) seems describe exactly this situation. But: When doing so, only links generated by Yesod will consider the approot, but the Route-definitions in the Quasiquoter parseRoutes will stay absolute:

```
mkYesod "App" [parseRoutes|
 / HomeR GET
|]
```

So setting APPROOT to "domain.com/path" will not work, since there's no route for "/path" but only for "/".

Is there a way to make the routes relative to the approot?

---

Update:

I tried to modify cleanPath accordingly too, but Routes to the Home-Route are still wrong…

```
instance Yesod Browser where
  approot = ApprootMaster myApproot
  cleanPath site s = do
        if corrected == s
            then Right $ dropprefix (Data.List.map dropDash s)
            else Left $ dropprefix corrected
      where
        corrected = Data.List.filter (not . Data.Text.null) s
        dropDash t
            | Data.Text.all (== '-') t = Data.Text.drop 1 t
            | otherwise = t
        r = Data.Text.drop 1 $ myApproot site
        l = Data.Text.length r
        dropprefix l
            | Data.List.take 1 l == [r] = Data.List.drop 1 l
            | otherwise = l
```

If I set approot to "/foo" it works, except for "@{HomeR}" leading to "/foo/" which redirects to "/foo/foo"…

Answer (score 2):

It's not completely clear what problem you're running into. I *think* what you're saying is, if you simply set APPROOT, then:

- The URLs generated by Yesod will include the `/path` prefix
- But incoming requests with the `/path` prefix will not be parsed correctly

The usual use case for this kind of prefix is that you have a reverse proxy in front of your app, such as Apache or Nginx, which is delegating only part of the domain to your app. In this case: APPROOT works fine.

I'm not sure what other use case you're trying to address, but in general you can just drop a part of the request path by overriding the [`cleanPath`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.3/yesod-core-1.4.36/Yesod-Core.html#v:cleanPath) method. Or you could use a WAI middleware to modify the request itself if you wanted.

Comment: Yes, that Is what I mean. I need this because I want to run the application on two different locations, once with an own domain where every routes are in "/", while the other time the app has to run inside a sub-folder of a domain.

Comment: I tried overriding the cleanPath method but I don't manage to do it correctly. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this in a single file example? It's not quite clear to me what error is occurring.

Comment: I stripped my code down to a minimal example: https://pastebin.com/vSKVLZDP

Comment: Your parsing logic isn't accounting for how the `/foo/` path is being parsed, which is `["foo", ""]`. You'll need special handling for the trailing empty string.